# Is there a list of which Steam games support Oculus Rift?

Tags: steam, oculus-rift

Steam has apparently started displaying when a game supports Oculus Rift; see for example [this game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/248470/?snr=1_4_4__101&featured_app=1).

Is there somewhere I can view all Steam games that have Oculus Rift support?  I noticed the "Advanced Search" has [VR Support](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?snr=1_4_4__12&term=#category2=31&sort_order=ASC&page=1) as an option, but it only returns 5 games...

Comment: Perhaps there are only 5 games that support it without mods?

Comment: I imagine as titles become more prevalent, we'll start seeing some VR icon in the side bar a la controller and Steam Cloud icons.

Comment: Steam store data is highly inconsistent and unreliable, being rife with arbitrarily inconsistent genre labels, released dates and other categorization. If you filter by trading cards, a good number of games aren't listed that do include trading cards. If you search "games," some DLC (separate category) and things not even games are mixed in. Sorting by date will filter out things it should not. Games with VR support may support Rift and simply lack the banner and many games with VR support will just not show in the search results. The only option is to check outside resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the "VR Support" list doesn't include the games that have the "Oculus Rift" banner (as shown on your link to Doorways: Chapter 1 and 2) and the fact that none of the games returned by that search query have the same banner, it would seem that this is functionality that has not yet been fully implemented and/or it could be for games supporting Valve's own upcoming virtual reality hardware.

However, there are a couple of manually maintained lists available;

- [This one on Steam contains quite a few more games](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=92979040) than are returned by the "VR Support" search query but doesn't seem to be actively updated anymore,
- [This one on Wikipedia is about games in general that support the Oculus Rift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_with_Oculus_Rift_support), not necessarily games specific to Steam,
- [Not specific to Steam, but RiftEnabled](http://www.riftenabled.com/) is a wiki-like site that keeps track of Rift support in games

There is also the [Oculus Rift Owners](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/oculus_rift) Group which may help you find out further information on which games directly support the Oculus Rift, but mainly seems to be full of tweaking games that don't officially support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

With the new addition of tags in steam, there is an Oculus Rift tag that seems to be used.
http://store.steampowered.com/tag/en/Oculus%20Rift/

Note that tags are in beta, and are entered by users themselves, so they are no guarantee but it seems to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Valve has added an Oculus filter to their search function. So you can go to Steam's search page, then check the Oculus Rift filter to get all the games with official Oculus support. Note that there are games with partial/alpha support for the Oculus Rift that this search will not find.

This also works for finding HTC Vive games on Steam.

At time of writing, the Oculus Touch has not been released, so be sure to do research on games to confirm you can use a controller, mouse & keyboard, etc. to control them if they list support for motion controllers.